# 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext' on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

> .Net Core 1.0.0 - SDK Preview 2 (x64)
>
> .Net Core 1.0.0 - VS "15" Preview 2 (x64)
>
> .Net Core 1.0.0 - Runtime (x64)

So, we updated an RC1 app to the latest versions above. After many hours of switching references, it's running. However, when logging in (AccountController/Login), I am getting an error at:

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    public SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager { get; private set; }
    private readonly IEmailSender EmailSender;

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        EmailSender = emailSender;
    }

    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(ViewModels.Account.LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Errs this next line
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false); // <-- ERRS HERE '.PasswordSignInAsync'
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password.");
            return View(model);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

It blows up with the following error message:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Here is the Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        // Add EF services to the services container.
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
           .AddDbContext<LogManagerContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:Connectionstring"]));

        services.AddSingleton(c => Configuration);

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LogManagerContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            
        
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        //Add all SignalR related services to IoC. - Signal R not ready yet - Chad
        //services.AddSignalR();

        //Add InMemoryCache
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.CookieName = ".LogManager";
        });

        // Uncomment the following line to add Web API servcies which makes it easier to port Web API 2 controllers.
        // You need to add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim package to project.json
        // services.AddWebApiConventions();
        // Register application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        
    }

    // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseSession();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        // Add the console logger.
        //loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information; - moved to appsettings.json -chad
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        loggerFactory.AddNLog();

        // Add the following to the request pipeline only in development environment.
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(DatabaseErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
        }
        else
        {
            // Add Error handling middleware which catches all application specific errors and
            // sends the request to the following path or controller action.
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        env.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config");

        // Add static files to the request pipeline.
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Add cookie-based authentication to the request pipeline.
        app.UseIdentity();

        //SignalR
        //app.UseSignalR();

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "default",
             template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
             );

            // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
            // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And here's the Context:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Add Custom Profile Fields
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LogManagerContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<LogEvent> LogEvents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogEventsHistory> LogEventsHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogEventsLineHistory> LogEventsLineHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogRallyHistory> LogRallyHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Flag> Flags { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Entity<LogEvent>().HasKey(x => x.LogId);
        builder.Entity<LogEvent>().ToTable("LogEvents");
        builder.Entity<Client>().HasKey(x => x.ClientId);
        builder.Entity<Client>().ToTable("Clients");
        builder.Entity<LogEventsHistory>().HasKey(x => x.HistoryId);
        builder.Entity<Flag>().HasKey(x => x.FlagId);
        builder.Entity<Flag>().ToTable("Flags");
        builder.Entity<LogRallyHistory>().HasKey(x => x.HistoryId);
        builder.Entity<LogEventsLineHistory>().HasKey(x => x.LineHistoryId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

> If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to
> the base constructor for DbContext.

The error message says your `DbContext`(`LogManagerContext` ) needs a constructor which accepts a `DbContextOptions`. But I couldn't find such a constructor in your `DbContext`. So adding the below constructor probably solves your problem.

```cs
public LogManagerContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}
```

**Edit for comment**

If you don't register `IHttpContextAccessor` explicitly, use below code:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: ok, so I added that to the LogManagerContext.cs and now I get a different error with even less info: 
InvalidOperationException: HttpContext must not be null.
get_Context
And I still cannot step into the .PasswordSignInAsync method either

Comment: Can you try to register IHttpContextAccessor? see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3936

Comment: services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
adding this to the Startup.cs fixed it. Thanks. If you want to repost that link I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @BeauD'Amore, shouldn't that be `services.addScoped` ?  A singleton would share state between requests and possible users.

Comment: @NathanGoings `HttpContextAccessor` is a factory method and gives you access to the current http context within the service where it is inserted to.

Answer (score 109):

I could resolve it by overriding Configuration in MyContext through adding connection string to the DbContextOptionsBuilder:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCoreConnectionString");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

**Install these packages** if the methods `SetBasePath` or `AddJsonFile` are not recognized :

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Comment: Nice, I forgot maybe the most important line : `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);`

Comment: please do not hard code connections string on OnConfiguring.. this will leak a security issue

Comment: @alhpe It is awesome to say that do not hard code connection strings there as it will leak a security issue. Probably, you could have mentioned what the alternative solution should be.

Comment: Use an OS environment variable and read it on your application

Comment: I think this is not a good solution. There must be another way to inject this configuration. It will be wonderful if someone may provide a proper way

Comment: Well, this is not a good solution but if you are in hurry, then it can work. Best would be to create the DBcontext in the Startup.cs in the Startup core project and then inject from there.

Comment: thanks, this is the easiest out-of-the-box solution when using the VS2019 ASP.NET Core MVC template

Comment: If you are missing `SetBasePath` or `AddJsonFile`, install those packages:
`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`
`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Comment: If you are missing UseSqlServer, install the package: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: I used IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to migrate the db in the project folder, and use the db in the bin folder at execution. When I started to use IdentityDbContext and IHost, the migration happened in the bin folder. The suggested solution worked for me.

Comment: This problem appeared for me in a mature .NET 6 application after changing a `Dictionary<,>` to a `SortedList<,>` in a referenced NuGet library. I reverted the change back, but this made it work with the `SortedList<,>`

Comment: This should be the first thing to try, for some reason the core6 pattern refuses to respect the configuration if done at the app builder side and the override that the EF scaffold tool creates is insufficient.

Answer (score 46):

This is the solution i found.

https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/entity-framework/core/dbcontext-configuration/index.md

Configure DBContext via AddDbContext

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db"));
}
```

Add new constructor to your DBContext class

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
      :base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Inject context to your controllers

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public MyController(BloggingContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ozan, you are the first person I have found who has mentioned injecting the context into the controller. Have a great day!

Comment: Yes, no one actually points out this ONLY works via injection, and your back end classes can't see that injection unless they're injected. So any backend usage of the context fails even though it looks like you've done everything right.

Comment: It still gives the same error. I had no controllers in my API (Data, Application and Domain are separated into projects), so I added and nothing changed.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is old but this answer still applies to newer Core releases.

If by chance your `DbContext` implementation is in a different project than your startup project and you run `ef migrations`, you'll see this error because the command will not be able to invoke the application's startup code leaving your database provider without a configuration. To fix it, you have to let `ef migrations` know where they're at.

`dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration [-p <relative path to DbContext project>, -s <relative path to startup project>]`

Both `-s` and `-p` are optionals that [default to the current folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options).

Comment: We also have the `DbContext` in a different project and as a workaround the EntityFrameworkCore.Design package was added to the Startup project (where it actually was not needed). With the -s parameter there is no need for the workaround

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the accepted answer, if anyone still getting the error even after doing followings correctly:

- In `Startup.cs` : `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => ... )`
- In `ApplicationDbContext.cs` : `public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options){}`

Check that **DbContext class does not have any parameterless public constructor** (need to delete it if any). FYI, you might be added parameterless public constructor for some reason i.e. Scaffolding DbContext.

Details (article that I wrote in my site): [ASP.Net Core troubleshooting](https://hovermind.com/aspnet-core/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 6):

I had this error despite having constructor with DbContextOptions parameter. Error showed up, when i changed solution startup from one to multiple projects. Check if you don't have multiple startup project in Solution -> Right Click -> Properties-> Common Properties -> Startup Project.

Comment: This solution solved my problem

Comment: just so you know, i logged in into my stackoverflow after 10 years only to upvote your answer because i lost like 2 hours on this newbie error. thanks pal !

Answer (score 4):

In my case, a fresh .NET6 Web API, the Scaffold-DbContext command added 2 Constructors like this:

```
 public BookStoreDbContext()
    {
    }

    public BookStoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<BookStoreDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

Just remove the first one and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Hi there I came across this question and my case is a little bit different
I try to test my AppDbContext file in not asp dot net core web application
so there is no a Dependency Injection to handle the step of adding a specific provider such as SQLServer so my solution is to override the following function in AppDbContext file:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    private string conn = "Server=servername;Database=dbName;Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true";
        
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn);
       }
}
```

in case you use the entity framework core with asp dot net web application you should add this configuration in the startup file in the ConfigureServices function  as follows :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        
            // name of your dbcontext file 
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option =>
            option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AlternativeConnection")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using top-level statement Program.cs make sure `builder.Services.AddDbContext<>` line is declared before this line:

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Override constructor of DbContext
Try this :-

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> option):base(option) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue using EF Core 6:

- 1st, I added a constructor without parameter in the context file
- 2nd, I overrided the OnConfiguring method in the same context file as follow:

  ```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    => options.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");
  ```
- Then run the migration

It worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had the wrong credentials. Classic confusing error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error when adding a new controller to my project, I solved it by entering the AppSetting, it had an extra "}" in the Json and this was generating the error, which would not let me make the connection.

I leave my humble contribution :) greetings

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was reworking some projects, and moved a lot of files.

The problem for me was, that I was missing:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

on the property group.

[image]

And thus startup.cs / program.cs did not be hit because its not flagged as an executing assembly.

So running the following without the missing reference:

```
dotnet ef migrations add {name} -c {my-context}
```

Resulted in the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.
```

After I added the reference the migrations succeeded. Silly mistake, but still a valuable lesson learned :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had this
`builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
before this
`.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));`.

Put `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` just before `builder.Build()` and all went well.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<...Context>(options =>
```

immediately after

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

in .NET6/8 and it runs perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).