# .NET Core 2 EF, object references are null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've started to use .NET Core 2 and databases for the first time and looked at examples like: [Getting Started with EF Core on .NET Core Console App with a New database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite). 
I've got a few models, like

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

But if I load an object, like `Post post = context.Post.SingleOrDefault(s => s.PostId == id)` then `post.Blog` is null. But if I before reading from the database, expand `context.Blogs` in the debugger, then `post.Blog` is a valid object after reading from the database with the above command.

So it feels like I need to read the blogs from the database to load those so the reference from Post will be correct. What is the correct way of doing this?

Second question: how to get the database context from anywhere? Should I have a default constructor with a connection string set in the constructor and create a new context all the time?

Comment: Built in dependency injection for your second question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: Eager and Explicit loading for your first question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data
EF core 2.0 doesn't support lazy loading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look here for detailed explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

A few examples from the link above:

**Eager loading**

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ToList();
}
```

**Explicit loading**

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = context.Blogs
        .Single(b => b.BlogId == 1);

    context.Entry(blog)
        .Collection(b => b.Posts)
        .Load();
}
```

**Lazy loading** is not yet supported. It should be coming in v2.1.

Comment: Thanks! I will look in to that! Btw, if I have a database singleton class, should I in each call create a new context? And use a default constructor without parameters..

Comment: @Mackan yes - create new context every time, never use signleton context, or you will have a lot of troubles.

Comment: @Evk If I have a default constructor, I get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745468/no-database-provider-has-been-configured-for-this-dbcontext And if I remove the parameterless constructor, then I can't create a context like that.

Comment: @Mackan well to be honest I have no idea about that, because I never create\update databases from EF, I always use "database first".

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep this updated for future reference, EF Core now supports lazy loading.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
=> optionsBuilder
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
    .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: You must install NuGet package `Microsoft.EntiryFrameworkCore.Proxies` for this to work (which it says in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

EF Core does not support lazy loading. You will need to eager load the objects  using .Include

The reason it worked when you called the Blogs first, is that the object was available in the context cache and hence it was able to populate the Blog object successfully.