# Cannot query SQL Server via Entity Framework "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to run this query:

```
public IList<User> GetList()
{
        using (var context = new MssqlContext())
        {
            // this throws the exception
            var query = from h in context.Users 
                        select h;

            var users = query.ToList<User>();
            return users;
        }
}
```

But on the marked line is this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

The problem might be because I haven't installed all essential libraries or I have badly written my `MssqlContext` class.

Libraries in my project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UrRG.jpg

My question is: What am I missing? This should to all intents and purposes work, but is doesn't.

Similar problem was solved here: ['No database provider has been configured for this DbContext' on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338475/no-database-provider-has-been-configured-for-this-dbcontext-on-signinmanager-p)

...but it didn't help me. Thanks you for any suggestions.

Class `MssqlContext`:

```
public class MssqlContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MssqlContext()
    {
        // Temporary solution.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);
        var config = builder.Build();
        //_connectionString = ConfigurationManager;
        _connectionString = config["ConnectionStrings:SAVConnectionString"];
    }
}
```

Comment: "A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider". All I see is a private _connectionString property that's never used. S.a. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: The provider is in the connection string.  So error is saying you to not have a valid connection string.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will look into it

Comment: @jdweng My connection string looks like this: "Data Source=DESKTOP-91JG566;Initial Catalog=db_SongsAndVotes;Integrated Security=true" Am I supposed to use another form?

Comment: The form is correct if the database (MDF file) is attached to a SQL Server.  Use SQL Server Management Studio to query the database.  Check the login window of SSMS.  It shold say Window Credential.  The server name and instance (server/instance) should be the one used for the Data Source.

Comment: @jdweng I do not see Window Credential anywhere https://imgur.com/a/UfayCSK. I am using the server name as DataSource like this: "SAVConnectionString": "Data Source=L211PC19;Initial Catalog=db_SongsAndVotes;Integrated Security=true" Is this correct?

Comment: The SSMS login windows has an authentication dropdown.  Line 1 is : Windows Authentication.  Line 2 is : SQL Server Authentication.  Integrated Security uses Windows Authentication.  So you should get  SSMS working before trying c#.  Windows Authentication requires the same user account to be on local and remote machines (Group Policy in a corporate network).  I can't see image in your link.  I blocked where I'm currently working and will look at the link this afternoon.