# Dependency Injection and Azure KeyVault Configuration

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-keyvault

I have an issue very much like the one mentioned in this post:

['No database provider has been configured for this DbContext' on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338475/no-database-provider-has-been-configured-for-this-dbcontext-on-signinmanager-p)

I want to use connection pooling and add my context like this:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

However I get the error :

> 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext' on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

The post suggests this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
           .Build();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCoreConnectionString");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
```

However instantiating a config object from appSettings like this ignores that my app service has injected a KeyVault secret into the IConfiguration object used elsewhere.

I really want to use the scoped IConfiguration which has my keyvault value but can't change the constructor because EF injects this DB context using the standard constructor.

Any ideas how I can inject the dependency and use an instance of the Configuration that has my key vault secret.

*Edit*
to answer to omissions from previous post

I am using .NET 7 and EF 7 and Duende.IdentityServer 6

My local app.settings file looks like this:

```
  {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=MyDdbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false"
  },
  "AppUrls": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:44317"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyAppName": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

however the default connection string is replaced with a KeyVault value in my app service:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/LiveDatabase/23423specialid345345)
```

I won't copy the whole startup code but this is it paraphrased:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
                {
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+'";
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.KeyManagement.DeleteRetiredKeys = false;
                    options.Csp.AddDeprecatedHeader = false;
                    options.Authentication.CheckSessionCookieName = "MyAppName.CheckSession";
                    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
                })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration["AppUrls:Url"]))                
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = dbBuilder =>
                        dbBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name));
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.EnablePooling = true;
                    options.PoolSize = 500;
                })
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .AddDbContextPool<MyDatabaseContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyAppName.Session";
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddJwtBearer("token", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration["AppUrls:Url"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "sub";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
                });
                

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyAppName.Antiforgery";
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });
            services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyAppName.TempCookie";
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

            services.Configure<AppUrls>(Configuration.GetSection("AppUrls"));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();            

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();                     

            if (!_env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var defaultCredentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                services.AddDataProtection()
                    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(
                        new Uri(Configuration["DataProtectionBlobUri"]!),
                        defaultCredentials)
                    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(
                        new Uri(Configuration["DataProtectionKeyVaultUri"]!),
                        defaultCredentials);
            }
        }
```

My App Db Context looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
            IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
        }
    }
```

Changing it to this works locally as the appsettings connection string is right:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
}

// adding this to my startup.cs
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

However when I push this to my live app service I then get the error:

> Keyword not supported: @microsoft.keyvault

It's worth pointing out my release pipeline does put the @microsoft in the default connection string in app settings but my app service configuration ignores it in place of the configuration value it sets.

However when using the Configuration Builder like this the app services app settings aren't taken into account.

Comment: hich dotnet / EF / apsnet version are you using ? also could you share your code please => it will help to try to reproduce. Thanks

Comment: What is the Framework and version of your WebApp. Please share your `appsettings.josn`  and  `.csproj` file.

Comment: @PaulMcCaffery - It will be easy to work from our end if you provide enough details to repro the issue.

Comment: I updated the original post with additional details requested