# Why do I get database provider error in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, dbcontext, provider

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project. I want put my SQL Server connection string in the `appsettings.json` file, and then use that in my entire project and the layers.

But I get the the provider error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

How can I fix this?

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CON1": "data source=DESKTOP-JU6B74d\\SQL2019;initial catalog = Laser; integrated security = true;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
},
```

This is the `program` file setting for the `DbContext`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CON1")));
```

And this is part of my `DbContext` in the data access layer:

```
public class DB : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DB() : base() { }

    public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder OptionsBuilder)
    {
        OptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"data source=DESKTOP-JU6B74d\SQL2019;initial catalog = Laser; integrated security = true;TrustServerCertificate=True;");
        base.OnConfiguring(OptionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I use this `DbContext`, I am not getting the provider error and program worked without problem. but in this form, I should repeat my connection string in the `DbContext` file, too.

So when I comment out the

```
protected override void OnConfiguring
```

method, I get the provider error. How can fix this and only read the connection string from the `appsettings.json` file - and why this problem even occurring?

Comment: Remove `DB`'s parameterless constructor.

Comment: when i remove this, I got error: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'options' of 'DB.DB(DbContextOptions<DB>)' DataAcessLayer C:\Users\sadegh\source\repos\SAED\DataAcessLayer\DALContents.cs 19 Active
" also I want remove override method. so i can read connection string only from appsetting file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['No database provider has been configured for this DbContext' on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338475/no-database-provider-has-been-configured-for-this-dbcontext-on-signinmanager-p)

Comment: I read this post before create my question. and not working for me. just before I write this answer, I find one solution. but I do not now if this is correct or not. correctly I remove the parameter less constructor. also remove the override method too. now all of my method that connect to database need DbContextOptions as parameter. So i inject this too all of my controllers, components, layers and all over my project that show error. the problem fix now and connection string only read from appsetting. if this solution correct or we can use the better way too?

Comment: also as I know the sting is case sensitive. but now when I change my connection string name in program file to coN1 (the name in appsetting is CON1). the program still work and not case sensitive anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [Examine the generated database context class and registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-generated-database-context-class-and-registration) to create the  database context class and registration.

database context class:

```
public class MvcMovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcMovieContext (DbContextOptions<MvcMovieContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

The constructor uses Dependency Injection to inject the database context (MvcMovieContext) into the controller:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;

    public MoviesController(MvcMovieContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Besides , Configuration keys are case-insensitive. For example, ConnectionString and connectionstring are treated as equivalent keys. You can  have a look at [Configuration keys and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-keys-and-values) to know more.

Comment: thank you. So I just need inject it too all my controller.

Comment: @sadegh , You are welcome:). And you are right.